# I'm writing flutter code, I got an error related to const (invalid constant value) , the code is shown below

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InputField extends StatelessWidget {
  const InputField(
    {
      @required this.labelText,
    @required this.onChanged,
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.validator,}
  );
  final String labelText;
  final void Function(String) onChanged;
   final IconData icon;
  final String Function(String) validator;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(icon),
        labelText:  labelText,
      ),
      onChanged: onChanged,
      validator: validator,
    );
  }
}
```

the error is in **(icon)**, the ide said "Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor."

the other one is in **labelText** and the error is "Invalid constant value".

I want to pass these arguments from outside to this stateless widget.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just remove the const from the constructor

```
class InputField extends StatelessWidget {
   InputField(
    {
      @required this.labelText,
    @required this.onChanged,
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.validator,}
  );
  final String labelText;
  final void Function(String) onChanged;
   final IconData icon;
  final String Function(String) validator;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(icon),
        labelText:  labelText,
      ),
      onChanged: onChanged,
      validator: validator,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @EkhlassT remove const before Input Decoration

Comment: @EkhlassT if you set it to const, you can't change it, there exist only one state of a const variable, but your TextFormField InputDecoration contains dynamic variable which might change

Comment: @EkhlassT cool, you can tick the answer if it solved your query

Answer (score 1):

the **const** keyword before InputDecoration was the problem.

the perfect code is

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InputField extends StatelessWidget {
   const InputField(
    {
      @required this.labelText,
    @required this.onChanged,
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.validator,}
  );
  final String labelText;
  final void Function(String) onChanged;
   final IconData icon;
  final String Function(String) validator;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration:  InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(icon),
        labelText:  labelText,
      ),
      onChanged: onChanged,
      validator: validator,
    );
  }
}
```